# How can I adjust the key that takes me to Insert Mode?

Tags: vim

The problem is that I find it very easy to accidentally insert stuff in Vim.

I know I can undo by with <kbd>U</kbd>, but it still is quite annoying and frequent. Often, I enter a command like `sp file.txt` without realizing that I haven't entered the `:` character yet (so I'm not yet on the command line).

Unfortunately, there are several characters that take you to insert mode, including `s`, `a`, `i`, `o`.

I'd rather have insert mode mapped to just one keybinding which is very deliberate, like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Can anyone point me to something that might have what I'm looking for?

Comment: Practice is all you need!

Comment: What you ask is technically possible and quite easy with a bunch of mappings but it also goes against how one is supposed to use Vim. You just need to get into the habit of typing `:` when necessary.

Comment: I agree with the other comments. This is a matter of practice, and sadly not much can (or moreover should) be done to fix the bad habit you experience. even if you alter it on your machine you'll only run into the issue the first time you run vim elsewhere. Best bet is to just go slower when learning, or use a cheat sheet of commands and bold the : on each command.

Comment: `sp 999data.txt` - "Vim: I don't want to delete!!!" etc etc. Maybe you should try cream (alternate Vim personality) or just learn to check the cursor position before typing an ex/: command?

Comment: Have you tried emacs? :-)

Comment: On one hand, I love the power that vim offers me, and I am glad to have learned it.  On the other, it is not the most learnable thing, even if forgiving.  A steep learning curve makes for an unpleasant experience...

Comment: I was afraid of this. The problem is that there are often times where I swear I pressed the colon key, but somehow it doesn't register. It might've been that I was not exactly in Normal mode when I thought I was, but in any case I will press the colon key and quickly proceed to my command, and it all happens so fast - the next thing I know I find myself overwriting my file...

Answer (score 1):

[Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/) - " a modern configuration of the Vim text editor"

> A single editing mode. (Cream does not
>   use Vim's modal editing unless turned
>   on from the Preferences menu.)
>
> How can I start command mode for the
>   occasional traditional Vim :command?
>
> Ctrl+L switches to normal mode along
>   with it's alternative Ctrl+\,Ctrl+N.
>
> Ctrl+B switches to normal mode for
>   only a single command.
>
> You can also select Expert Mode from
>   the Settings menu to toggle between
>   Normal and Insert mode with the Esc
>   key.